# Cell Counting: Selective; Only count cells positive for all stainings

Tags: python, opencv, imaging, imagej

If I take multiple images in different fluorescent channels (after staining the cells with some antibody/maker), how can I automatically quantitate the fraction of cells positive for each marker? Has anyone done something like this in Python?

I can already use Fiji (ImageJ) to count the cells containing only one staining type, but I can't make it run a selective count on merged images which contain two staining types. Since Fiji interacts well with python, I was thinking of writing a script that looks at each respective image containing only one staining type and then obtain the x-y coordinates of the respective image and check for matches between. I am not sure if that's a good idea though and I was wondering, if anyone has done something similar or has a more efficient way of getting the task done?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use cont = cv2.findcontours to find the almost round shaped cells and count them 
with len(cont).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately your hint doesn't take me all the way, i.e. it doesn't give me back a count of only the cells which fulfill both criteria (i.e. contain both types of staining). I've done something similar to what you were proposing, using jython. That also works perfectly fine for giving me back a pretty accurate cellcount for each respective image,- but i still don't know how to make the program detect the matches between the two images in order to give me back the count of only those cells, which include both stainings...